# Bash script calling Python with sleep

Tags: bash

I want to call a Python file named main.py using a bash script in the same folder.

Bash script must call the Python file randomly between 2pm and 6pm once a day.

I would use a random sleep.

NOTE: it should be executed randomly. For example starting at 0 seconds of the minute is not a random time!

How would you write this bash script to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Use `cron` to schedule the python script directly

Comment: @Vinny cron doesn't do random times very well

Comment: Add your python script a random sleep when it loads then

Answer (score 1):

This code can help. It runs the python script in a random minute between the interval you want to. Also this `bash` script should be added to crontab file to be scheduled at 02.00PM.

```
#!/bin/bash
maxtime=$((4*60*60))
delay=$(($RANDOM%maxtime))
(sleep $((delay)); /usr/bin/python /path/to/yourscript.py) &  #background the sleep process, then run your script
```

Comment: NOTE: it should be executed randomly. For example starting at 0 seconds of the minute is not a random time!

Comment: Answer edited to run in random seconds between 2.00pm and 6.00pm.

Answer (score 0):

You could use cron to run the bash script @1400, and the bash script would have a random number of minutes to sleep less than 240 (4 hours * 60 minutes). When sleep runs out, call the python.

I assume you know about $RANDOM?

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep $(( $RANDOM % 240 ))m
./mypython.py
```

To account for new constraints in the edit:

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep $(( $RANDOM % 240))m
sleep $(( $RANDOM % 60))
./mypython.py
```

Comment: Please post the bash script for better understanding.

Comment: NOTE: it should be executed randomly. For example starting at 0 seconds of the minute is not a random time!